# mandar emails con código html usando la librería javax.mail

Tags: java, java-ee, email, servlets

Estoy tratando de enviar correos con código html adjunto, pero en el correo que mando pone el codigo tal cual en lugar de interpretarlo el navegador.

```
public class EmailUtility {
    public static void sendEmail(String host, String port,
            final String userName, final String password, String toAddress,
            String subject, String message) throws AddressException,
            MessagingException {

        // sets SMTP 
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

        // autenticador
        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
            public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
            }
        };

        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);

        // creando el mensaje de e-mail
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userName));
        InternetAddress[] toAddresses = { new InternetAddress(toAddress) };
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        msg.setText(message);

        // enviando el e-mail
        Transport.send(msg);

    }
}
```

el metodo para mandar el email

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
        String port = "587";
        String user = "**************";
        String  pass = "****";

        String resultMessage = "";
        String content = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n"
                + "<html>\n"
                + "<head>\n"
                + "<style>\n"
                + "table {\n"
                + "  border-collapse: collapse;\n"
                + "  width: 100%;\n"
                + "}\n"
                + "\n"
                + "th, td {\n"
                + "  text-align: left;\n"
                + "  padding: 8px;\n"
                + "}\n"
                + "\n"
                + "tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}\n"
                + "\n"
                + "th {\n"
                + "  background-color: #4CAF50;\n"
                + "  color: white;\n"
                + "}\n"
                + "</style>\n"
                + "</head>\n"
                + "<body>\n"
                + "\n"
                + "<h2>Colored Table Header</h2>\n"
                + "\n"
                + "<table>\n"
                + "  <tr>\n"
                + "    <th>Firstname</th>\n"
                + "    <th>Lastname</th>\n"
                + "    <th>---------</th>\n"
                + "  </tr>\n"
                + "  <tr>\n"
                + "    <td>Peter</td>\n"
                + "    <td>Griffin</td>\n"
                + "    <td>$100</td>\n"
                + "  </tr>\n"
                + "  <tr>\n"
                + "    <td>Lois</td>\n"
                + "    <td>Griffin</td>\n"
                + "    <td>$150</td>\n"
                + "  </tr>\n"
                + "  <tr>\n"
                + "    <td>Joe</td>\n"
                + "    <td>Swanson</td>\n"
                + "    <td>$300</td>\n"
                + "  </tr>\n"
                + "  <tr>\n"
                + "    <td>Cleveland</td>\n"
                + "    <td>Brown</td>\n"
                + "    <td>$250</td>\n"
                + "</tr>\n"
                + "</table>\n"
                + "\n"
                + "</body>\n"
                + "</html>";

        try {
            EmailUtility.sendEmail(host, port, user, pass, email, subject,
                    content);
            resultMessage = "el email fue enviado";
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            resultMessage = " error: " + ex.getMessage();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("se envio el email");

        }
    }
```

**si se envia el correo pero la estructura html llega como codigo tal cual no es interpretado**

Comment: El problema es que estás usando `msg.setText(message);`. El método `setText` tiene por defecto un tipo de contenido `text/plain`. Si quieres enviar contenido HTML puedes usar el método `setContent`  del siguiente modo: **`msg.setContent(message, "text/html; charset=utf-8");`**

Comment: muchisimas gracias ya se mando mi correo como quería.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que el método `setText` que estás usando tiene por defecto `tex/plain`, como dice la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setText-java.lang.String-):

> Método de conveniencia que establece la cadena dada como el contenido
>   de esta parte, con un tipo MIME `text/plain` ...

En lugar de `setText` puedes usar [**`setContent`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setContent-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-), el cual te permite especificar otro tipo MIME, en este caso `text/html`, de paso le puedes indicar también el juego de caracteres:

```
msg.setContent(message, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
```